# HTML5 video performance

Tags: linux-mint, performance, video, youtube

I have performance problem with video playing:

When I am playing video on youtube, high CPU percentage is used: 
[image: HTML5 video CPU usage]

But when I download the same video and play it in VLC player, CPU usage is reduced by half: 
[image: VLC cpu usage]

Please help.
(Linux Mint 17.2 MATE 64bit, HP ProBook 4330s)

Comment: Check if hardware acceleration is enabled in VLC.

Comment: I guess it's disabled: http://i7.5cm.ru/i/A02T.png.  
The same in chromium: http://i7.5cm.ru/i/wrrM.png

Comment: Found [a](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112092/high-cpu-usage-when-watching-youtube-videos-html5) [few](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1163327) [reports](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=970308) of similar problems, but no solution. Looks like HTML5 is slower than native playback in all browsers :(

Answer (score 0):

*sorry can't comment*

1. Check if it gets better if you turn hardware acceleration on.
2. Download the video, open with Chrome (which seems to be your browser). If it uses less CPU, it's a problem with how your browser plays HTML5 video and you can fix it by opening the video in new tab (which sadly will be problematic with Youtube and the similar). If it uses the same amount, it's a problem with how your browser plays videos, and the only way to fix it may be updating or changing your browser.

PS: are you using 32-bit version of Chrome? It stopped being supported a few months ago, and is likely to have bugs.